# How to fetch sorted paginator.posts in Jekyll?

Tags: sorting, pagination, jekyll

I am struggling this for several hours. I have a Jekyll site with the following index.html

```
---
layout: default
---
<div class="home">

    <div class="post-box">  
        <h2 class="post-main-description">Programming Languages Notes</h2>
        <ul class="post-list">
            {% assign sorted_pages = paginator.posts | sort:"title" %}

            {% for post in sorted_pages %}
                <li>
                <h2>
                    <a class="post-link" href="{{ post.url | prepend: site.baseurl }}">{{ post.title }}</a>
                </h2>
                </li>
            {% endfor %}
            <div class="pagination">
                {% if paginator.previous_page %}
                <a href="{{ paginator.previous_page_path }}" class="previous">Previous</a>
                {% else %}
                <span class="previous">Previous</span>
                {% endif %}
                <span class="page_number ">Page: {{ paginator.page }} of {{ paginator.total_pages }}</span>
                {% if paginator.next_page %}
                <a href="{{ paginator.next_page_path }}" class="next">Next</a>
                {% else %}
                <span class="next ">Next</span>
                {% endif %}
            </div>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Without pagination the site can successfully sort the pages by their titles.

Like so :

```
001. Variables and Bindings
002. Tail Recursion
003. Fast Track to Functional Paradigm
004. Introduction to Types
005. Implementing One-of-type in Java
006. Records in SML
007. Case Expressions
008. Truth about Lists
009. Functional Paradigm Warm-up
```

But when I introduce pagination it looks like this

```
005. Implementing One-of-type in Java
006. Records in SML
007. Case Expressions
008. Truth about Lists
009. Functional Paradigm Warm-up
First Page >>

001. Variables and Bindings
002. Tail Recursion
003. Fast Track to Functional Paradigm
004. Introduction to Types
Last Page
```

How can I fetch the sorted posts on the first page?

Thanks.

Comment: I have the exact same issue. I guess there is no fix?